# SQL Developer and SQL Programmers same?

Tags: sql

Are SQL Developers and SQL Programmers same people? I have basic knowledge about SQL and want to improve it. plz help me?

Answer (score 5):

No, I disagree - if you read Mike Gunderloy's excellent book [Coder to Developer](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/078214327X) you'll understand a developer is a coder - but also a lot more.

A **coder** (= programmer) typically only writes code (possibly including unit tests) and that's about it. He usually gets a clear spec or task from someone else. A coder/programmer is more or less only concerned with writing, testing, and verifying code - nothing more.

A **developer** is a much more encompassing job description - a developer also deals with putting things into perspective, breaking up tasks into chunks that a coder can work on, he spends his time thinking about deployment and a lot more. A developer needs to know a lot more in his daily job than a coder.

Comment: +1 - and if I could, another +1 for the book recommendation.

Comment: thank you. It amazing to get good answer in so little time.

Comment: In common usage coder == programmer == developer, especially outside of coding/development/programming. This includes HR and recruiters.

Comment: I've never actually come across anyone that uses the term "coder" in common usage. The term is simply is not sufficiently pervasive. IMO, a better distinction would be "architect/system designer" vs programmer/coder. Non-developers are (slightly) better able to pick up that an architect or system designer might involve more than typing curly braces.

Answer (score 3):

Mike's book is good ... but if your going for a job the two terms SQL Programmer <-> SQL Developer are pretty much interchangable.

It just depends on what the hiring manager feels like calling the position.

Comment: Thanks. But do we use programmer and developer terms interchangeably?

Comment: @Subodh: depends who you mean by "we" :-). Mostly for developers they are subtly different (what marc_s said, but implied rather than explicit); for non-developers they are the same.

Comment: I disagree. I develop software and am proud to be called a programmer, I don't make a distinction. What about Siebel's latest book 'Coders at Work'. Interviews with some of the greatest programmers :- Ken Thompson, Josh Bloch, Douglas Crockford, Brad Fitzpatrick. I think these guys break up tasks and think about deployment too. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try [SQL Exercises](http://www.sql-ex.ru/) to improve your skills in SQL.

Comment: Thank you very much. I find SQL Exercise site very useful to me. Using the book, my learning was not as much as i desired. Thanks.